# show/hide control video at a full screen window

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

Is there a way to show/hide the video controls on the videojs player at a fullscreen window? (e.g. player.controls.hide()).

this is my code

```
player.on('fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    if (player.isFullscreen()) {
        player.on('mouseout', function(){ 
          player.controlBar.addClass('vjs-fade-out'); 
        });

        player.on('mouseover', function(){ 
          player.controlBar.removeClass('vjs-fade-out'); 
        });
    } else {
        player.controls(true);
      }
    });
```

but isn't work for auto hide

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/options.html

You could try:

```
$('#playerId').removeAttr('controls');
```